# How do I detect invalid UTF-8 strings being passed to a Tomcat app?

Tags: java, tomcat, utf-8

While testing a new web app, I happened to cut and paste a string from another browser window into the input form of my web app.   This string had a specific character in it, a single close-quote (byte value 146, hex 92).  You can see the character by going to [Yelp](http://www.yelp.com/biz/martins-auto-repair-phoenix) and looking at the name of the company:

```
Martin’s Auto Repair.
```

The character cut and pasted correctly, but when I submitted the form, it got mangled:

```
Martinâs Auto Repair
```

Subsequent submits increased the mangling:

```
MartinÃ¢ÂÂs Auto Repair
MartinÃÂ¢ÃÂÃÂs Auto Repair
MartinÃÂÃÂ¢ÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂs Auto Repair
```

My JSP page, my Tomcat server and my app are all set to use UTF-8 so it appears that it's trying to read this character as the first character of a UTF-8 multi-byte character and mangling it somehow.

I'd love to know the intricacies of this, of course, but I'm more interested in **stopping this behavior.**

Anyone know how to avoid this?

Comment: "ASCII value 146" doesn't exist - ASCII is a 7-bit encoding. It's important to work out which *Unicode code point* you're interested in, what bytes are being sent to the server, what encoding the browser is specifying, etc.

Comment: Sorry, whatever you want to call it - a byte with value 146.    I came from "back in the day" when ASCII was **it**.

Comment: But it's not a byte - it's a character. That's the point. It looks to me as if you want U+2019, which is represented in UTF-8 as bytes E2 80 99. But you really need to work out which encoding is being used at each step of the process, and where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Really Jon is right. Somewhere in your handling chain you're not handling unicode characters properly and more information is needed. That being said, I can only think of two places in normal servlet/JSP flows on tomcat where you need to check it so I'll attempt an answer:

First, check your tomcat configs. The `URIEncoding` attribute of the [http connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes) needs to be set to `UTF-8`. With this set, the string passed into the servlet should be correctly decoded. You may want to temporarily log the value you get to verify it's correct here.

Second, check the character coding of your JSP pages output. I *believe* the default encoding for JSPs should handle unicode but it's worth checking the headers/html coming to the browser as this could also be your issue.

Either one of those two could cause the issues you're seeing. Unless you or a framework you're using is doing the encoding/decoding somewhere this should solve your problem.